# Windows 7 software to do voice calls over modem? Dialer.exe doesn't work as expected

Tags: windows-7, modem

I am using  dialer.exe to dial a voice phone call from Windows 7.
but, the problem is that I  can hear the recipient of the phone call, but recipient cannot hear me.

So, what is the name of some software to handle voice portion of call?

Answer (score 3):

Phone Dialer (dialer.exe) is exactly what it says it is: a dialer. According to Microsoft's [help pages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958143), you will need to be sure that your modem supports both voice and data connections.

Instead of using a separate piece of software, you also have the option to pick up a handset connected to the same line as your modem, and you should be able to speak.

I don't know how much software there is out there to handle the voice portion. You may be better off using a service like [Google Talk](http://talk.google.com/) (free within the United States until at least the end of the year) or [Skype](http://www.skype.com/) (free for computer-to-computer).

Comment: Thanx for your reply..
but , i dont have to use handset. i need to make calls through software only.. If you r having any information

Comment: @abha This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've converted your answer to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I was looking for a solution to make/receive phone calls using PC, modem, telephony software and landline. Strictly, I do not want to use Internet/VOIP.

I bought a PROLINK 56K USB Fax/Data Modem 1456UC. Installed on my PC, it works fine.
Dial the telephone number using Windows 7 Phone Dialer. Talk using normal phone.